# Convert column with number (string) into into float and integer

Tags: python, pandas, function, if-statement, casting

I want to ask for solution to my problem. I have a dataframe column (string type data) and want to convert it into float and integer data type. In that column it has two type of number. The first type is number with '.' --> I want to convert it into float data type, and the second type is number without '.' --> I want to convert it into integer data type.
[image]

So I made a function like this:

```
def cek_string(x):
    if '.' in x :
       result = x.astype(float)
    else:
       result = x.astype(int)
    return result
```

And I want to apply that function into my dataframe columns:

```
df['TotalCharges'] = df['TotalCharges'].apply(lambda x : cek_string(x))
```

But I get warning message like this : 'str' object has no attribute 'astype'

Is there any solution?

Comment: Don't apply it to the whole dataframe but only "TotalCharges" column.

Comment: Well `7590-VHVEG` is not a numeric value.  Check your data.

Comment: In pandas at least, you can't have heterogeneous data types in the same column.

Comment: BTW, if you have defined a function, you can just do `.apply(cek_string)`, no need to use a lambda there.